# How does one keep CSS3 animation state after ng-animate?

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate

I am trying to change a div' state using `ng-animate` + CSS3 transitions.

My animations works just fine with this CSS except for the fact that the div doesn't keep its size + color once the animation is done.

```
.fade-hide, .fade-show {                                                                                                                                     
  -webkit-transition:all linear 1s;                                                                                                                          
  -moz-transition:all linear 1s;                                                                                                                             
  -o-transition:all linear 1s;                                                                                                                               
  transition:all linear 1s;  
}                                                                                                                                                            
.fade-hide {                                                                                                                                                 
  opacity:1;                                                                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                                            
.fade-hide.fade-hide-active {                                                                                                                                
  opacity:0;                                                                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                                            
.fade-show {                                                                                                                                                 
  opacity:0;                                                                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                                            
.fade-show.fade-show-active {                                                                                                                                
  opacity:1;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}
```

I have already tried using `animation-fill-mode:forwards;` but its state is still not preserved.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rxdazn/pJMQc/1/)

Comment: In the .jsfiddle, .fade-show and .fade-show-active classes are being removed by javascript from the parent div when the animation finishes. Since the styles and visibility are associated with those classes, once the animation completes and they are removed, the html removes the color and height attributes.

This isn't really an answer - I'm not familiar with ng-animate, but maybe it can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to keep the properties after the effects the html object need a separate class, because the `fade-show` and the `fade-show-active` classes will be removed when the effect ends.

The new fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/WufYs/1/

The CSS:

```
.fade-hide, .fade-show {                                                                                                                                     
    -webkit-transition:all linear 1s;                                                                                                                          
    -moz-transition:all linear 1s;                                                                                                                             
    -o-transition:all linear 1s;                                                                                                                               
    transition:all linear 1s;  
}    
.fade.fade-show.fade-show-active,
.fade.fade-hide {                                                                                                                                                 
    opacity:1;
    height: 200px;
}                                                                                                                                                            
.fade.fade-hide.fade-hide-active,
.fade.fade-show {                                                                                                                                
    opacity:0;    
    height: 0px;
}                                                                                                                      
.fade{
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
}
```

You can find more examples at [nganimate.org](http://www.nganimate.org) website

Comment: Any idea how to make this work with Firefox?  It seems to fail during show, when going from `display:none` to another value.